# control my skeleton HTML5 with css3 by Media Query

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing a website in PC version and I'd like to add some versions with Media Query for the mobile versions,

I learned this using the css3 except that the question I ask myself how can I change the structure with css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
 <body>
<?php 
$id = $_POST['T0']; // Recuperer le identifiant 
$nom = $_POST['T1'];// Recuperer le nom 
$prenom = $_POST['T2']; // Recuperer le prenom 
?>
  <form method="POST" action="myphp.php"> <br>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td>Identifiant</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="T0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>nom</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="T1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>prenom</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="T2"></td>
</tr>


 </table>
 <input type="Submit" name="button" value="Envoyer Request"> 
 </form>
 <br> <center><h1 style="color: red;">
<?php
echo "bienvenue $nom $prenom votre identifiant est $id";
?>

</h1></center>
 </body>
</html>
```

example in my computer version I have:

```
<p> a sentence

<Table>
```

what I want is on my mobile version that it is:

```
<Table>

<p> a sentence
```

is it possible to do with CSS or do I have to modify HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS only styles elements. It can't modify the HTML itself, so you'll indeed have to modify the HTML itself.

Note that there exists some CSS properties that allows yo to give the impression that some elements were in a different order in the HTML, like [flex-order](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.right-order {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrong-order {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-order">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrong-order">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
</div>
```